# Is it safe for my password hint to be synonymous to my password?

Tags: passwords

Lets say my password is `AppleDogFire642!`.

What would be the potential security consequences if my password hint was `BananaCatSmoke123@`?

Comment: it looks like you're using three dicewords and a short suffix, so giving this away in the hint would almost certainly give an advantage to a human adversary - is your goal to have everything you need to log in available on the login screen of the host? or could you introduce a second device?

Comment: Would it be safe *from what*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I saw `BananaCatSmoke123@` and it didn't work, then I would most certainly start replacing words, numbers, and symbols.

You not only give away your pattern, but the context behind each word. You reduce the entropy for the attacker considerably. So instead of `Apple` providing 5 characters from a 52-symbol set (26 lower-case letters, 26 upper-case), it represents a common fruit, a set of 10-20 options.

So, such a hint makes it considerably easier for someone to guess your password.

Answer (score 1):

A password hint should be just that: A hint.

For example, if you have 3 passwords with high entropy, which you use on systems where using a password manager isn't possible, then the password hint should be something that hints you towards *which* password you have chosen.

For example, say you have the following three passphrases:

- `Legendary Equal Enforcer Stubby Berlin Tower`
- `Obligatory Sawmill Stoic Landscape Fast Swing`
- `Seven Key Purple Dreaming Dramazic Queue`

Your password hint could literally be `L`, `O`, or `S` respectively. While yes, it *does* reveal something about your password, it's merely one letter. The purpose of the hint should be to remind you which of the passwords you had chosen, not what the password is.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about what security implications there might be if the OP's goes through with their plan. And this is awfully hyper-specific to your arbitrary setup for passwords. What you appear to say is simply that the hint should should not expose anything of the password.

Comment: @schroeder Yeah, i don't know where I was going with that sentence. I hope it's clearer now. And yes, on second thought, it doesn't directly answer the question. Delete it if you think it's too off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

**No, this is not safe.** Your password hint needs to be useful only to *you*.

Let's say you change password schemes every once in a while. You could denote not the scheme but the date, so you could say "uses 2022 pw scheme" to remind yourself without actually revealing the scheme. (I actually did this until my last scheme change, which simply tells me to use my password manager. Password managers are the only viable solution here since password strength is inversely proportional to memorability.)

Before I switched to a password manager, I used a prescribed scheme and wrote clues on a note in my wallet. The site hint would simply point me there, like `wallet 13` to denote the 13th item on the list, which itself was a cryptic clue only I could understand. That would the the appropriate place to write `BananaCatSmoke123@`.

(I like using my wallet because it's always on me. If somebody is digging through my wallet, that's an obvious invasion of my privacy. This is much better than a sticky note under the keyboard.)

Answer (score 0):

The potential security consequence is that someone can figure out the password, authenticate and steal information or sabotage the person/system. This is not a consequence of the specific approach that you propose, it is a weakness of password-based authentication mechanisms *in general*.

In your case, the approach seems to be based on people not being able to make any association between the hint and the password. For the average person this may be true, but for a knowledgeable adversary this is usually not the case.

Here are some potential problems I see with your approach:

1. The structures of your password and hint are identical and strict; 3 words, 3 digits and 1 special symbol. This gives a leverage to an adversary, because they know how to construct a password and try it against the authentication system
2. Assuming that there's an 1-1 correspondence of the words between the hint and the password, the words belong to the same semantic family (animals, fruits etc) which reduces the search space by *a lot*
3. Assuming that you're using natural language words (e.g. english, as in your example), your password is susceptible to dictionary attacks. Since the hint is public info and provides the families of the words that the password uses, this is a major concern (given point 2 above)

The authentication system that is used, also plays a significant role:

- If it's an offline system (e.g. hard disk encryption) then an adversary can steal it (e.g. make a copy of the encrypted disk) and try as many times as required in order to break in
- If it's an online system (e.g. web site) then several factors play their role too:
  (a) Does the system restrict the number of failed password attempts?
  (b) Does the system use a secure key derivation function to store your password (e.g. argon2)?
  (c) If the system is a user authentication system, does it have multi-factor-authentication (MFA) enabled?

Finally, the most important question is: what are you trying to protect? Low value, low impact info doesn't require sophisticated protection approaches. Top secret government info requires a lot more than that.